# All bounded sequence of $\mathcal{L}^2$ is weakly relatively compact of?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and  $\{f_n\}\subset \mathcal{L}^2$, such that:
$$
\sup_n \int_{E}{|f_n(t)|^2d\mu(t)}<+\infty
$$

Why $\{f_n\}$ is weakly relatively compact of $\mathcal{L}^2$?

Comment: Look up the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem

Comment: Can you give me the first step of proof?

Comment: The first step of the proof is applying Banach-Alaoglu. You should try that and if you can't get it to work out edit your question to include your attempt and why you get stuck.